# M-Theory: Are the branes still colliding and matter is being produced into our universe?

Tags: string-theory

In [M-Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory) membranes are rippling in the 11th dimension and when they collided the bing bang happened and the ripples produced matter, is it still happening and matter is still being produced?

Pardon me if I miss something, also would like to understand 11 dimensions and M-theory, any good resource for a computer engineer who has a hobby of studying physics(can't really solve and understand those complex mathematical equations, but will try every bit to learn and understand them).

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the equation free popular books, you could try to read David McMohan's [Demystified](http://www.amazon.com/String-Theory-Demystified-David-McMahon/dp/0071498702) book. It is targed at readership who wants to self study stuff and if you cant get enough, it should prepare you for an easier start if you want to start a "real" text book too. But be sure to know a bit about complex analysis, quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, and general relativity before. David McMohan has written Demystified books about these topics too for the same kind of audience.